# React native app crashes without any error log for multiple same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working with React Native app. Version 0.70

I am stuck with an weired problem. The problem is that React Native app crashes without any error log to console.

My code where mainly the crashes occurs is given below:

```
import {
    ImageBackground,
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput as Input,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Pressable
} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { ROUTES } from '../../../constants';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { FUNCTIONS } from '../../../helpers';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import {
    GET_ALL_QUESTION_BY_USER_ID_QUERY,
    GET_CONTEST_BY_CONTEST_ID_QUERY,
    UPDATE_CONTEST_MUTATION
} from '../../../graphql/query';
import { UPDATE } from '../../../graphql/contestMutation';
import UpdateItem from '../../../components/Author/UpdateItem';

const EditContest = ({ route }) => {
    const [newData, setNewData] = useState({});
    const [question, setQuestion] = useState([]);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { contestId } = route.params;

    const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5'];
    const handleSelect = selectedOptions => {
        console.log('Selected options:', selectedOptions);
    };
    const handleOptionPress = option => {
        const isSelected = selectedOptions.includes(option);
        if (isSelected) {
            setSelectedOptions(pre => pre.filter(item => item !== option));
        } else {
            setSelectedOptions(pre => [...pre, option]);
        }
    };

    const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_CONTEST_BY_CONTEST_ID_QUERY, {
        variables: { id: contestId }
    });

    const {
        loading: questionLoading,
        error: questionError,
        data: questionData
    } = useQuery(GET_ALL_QUESTION_BY_USER_ID_QUERY, { variables: { token: auth.token } });

    const [updateNow, { loading: updateLoading, error: updateError, data: updateData }] =
        useMutation(UPDATE_CONTEST_MUTATION);

    const [update, { loading: updLoading, error: updError, data: updData }] = useMutation(UPDATE);

    const submitUpdate = () => {
        updateNow({ variables: { ...newData, questions: selected, id: contestId } });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            const optionsDefault = data.getContestByContestId.Questions.map(item => item.id);
            setSelected(optionsDefault);
            setNewData({
                title: data.getContestByContestId.title,
                description: data.getContestByContestId.description,
                duration: data.getContestByContestId.duration,
                start: data.getContestByContestId.start,
                privacy: data.getContestByContestId.privacy,
                password: data.getContestByContestId.password
            });
        }
    }, [data]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (questionData) {
            const array = questionData.getAllQuestionByUserId.map(item => ({
                key: item.id,
                value: item.title
            }));
            setQuestion(array);
        }
    }, [questionData]);

    if (!updateLoading && updateData) {
        console.log(updateData);
        FUNCTIONS.showToast2(updateData.updateContest.status, updateData.updateContest.message);
        navigation.navigate(ROUTES.AUTHOR_CONTEST);
    } else if (updateError) console.log(false, updateError.message);

    if (loading || error || !newData) {
        <SafeAreaView>
            <ScrollView>
                <View className="h-screen px-2 py-1 w-screen bg-white">
                    <View className="w-full items-center justify-center border-b-4 border-green-500 bg-green-100 rounded p-2">
                        <Text className="font-bold text-xl ">Update Contest</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>;
    } else
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                <View className="h-screen px-2 py-1 w-screen bg-white">
                    <View className="w-full items-center justify-center border-b-4 border-green-500 bg-green-100 rounded p-2">
                        <Text className="font-bold text-xl ">Update Contest</Text>
                    </View>
                    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        <View className="rounded overflow-hidden my-1">
                            <ImageBackground
                                source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/900' }}
                                className="w-full h-[140px]"
                            />
                            <View className="w-full bg-[#2B3467] p-1">
                                <Text className="font-bold text-xl text-gray-50">
                                    {data.getContestByContestId.title}
                                </Text>
                            </View>

                            <View className="flex space-y-2">


                                <View className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </View>
                                {/* <TouchableOpacity className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity> */}
                                
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <Pressable
                        className="w-full bg-[#2B3467] p-2 my-2 rounded items-center"
                        onPress={submitUpdate}>
                        <Text className="font-bold text-white text-lg">Update</Text>
                    </Pressable>
                </View>
                {/* </ScrollView> */}
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
};

export default EditContest;
```

When I put View component for 3 or more times the app crases. But for 2 or less time it works fine.

```
<View className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View className="w-full p-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-1 bg-white rounded">
                                    <Text>Option A</Text>
                                </View>
```

I was actually working to make a multiple select input. Then the problem occured. Finally I figured out the problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is highly likely that the console will not display errors if there are issues with your setup.

One issue that I can easily observe is the first condition check in JSX.

```
 if (loading || error || !newData) ...
```

**you are not returning anything.**